# Python NetworkX - get DiGraph from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, graph, networkx, digraphs

I am trying to create a simple DiGraph in python's NetworkX from nested dictionary but it looks like built in initialization doesn't built final leaf nodes.

Toy example:

```
class_hierarchy= {-1: ["A", "B"], 
"A":{"A1":[1], "A2":[3,4]}, 
"B": {"B1":[5,6], "B2": [7,8]}}
```

Building graph:

```
G = DiGraph(class_hierarchy)
```

Now let's see what we have in it:

```
G.nodes
Out[86]: NodeView((-1, 'A', 'B', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2'))
```

Looks like final nodes are not added

Checking it:

```
list(G.successors('A'))
Out[88]: ['A1', 'A2']
```

Looks reasonable

But:

```
list(G.successors('A1'))
Out[89]: []
```

I am not sure why this is the case? [Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html#networkx.DiGraph) for NetworkX specifies that:

incoming_graph_data (input graph (optional, default: None)) – Data to initialize graph. If None (default) an empty graph is created. The data can be any format that is supported by the to_networkx_graph() function, currently including edge list, **dict of dicts**, dict of lists, etc...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mixed input which is both a `dict of lists` and both a `dict of dicts`.
`Networkx` will interpretate it as `dict of lists`.
See the [following code](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/convert.py), where `data` is `class_hierarchy` in your case.

```
if isinstance(data, dict):
        try:
            #this will raise an exception
            return from_dict_of_dicts(data, create_using=create_using,
                                  multigraph_input=multigraph_input)
        except:
            try:
                # this is what is called in your case
                return from_dict_of_lists(data, create_using=create_using)
            except:
                raise TypeError("Input is not known type.")
```

In your case, `networkx` expects a dictionary of lists adjacency representation.
For instance, the expected input is of the form : `key: value` -> `node u: list of nodes [v1,v2,...,vn] u is connected with` (e.g., {0: [1,2], 1: [3,4]}.

What networkx does with you input you give is as follows:

```
G=nx.DiGraph()

edges_list = [((node, nbr)) for node, nbrlist in d.items() for nbr in nbrlist]
# [(-1, 'A'), (-1, 'B'), ('A', 'A1'), ('A', 'A2'), ('B', 'B1'), ('B', 'B2')]

G.add_edges_from(edges_list)
```

Thus, you have to change your format according to the meaning you give to it.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I really confused those two formats. Huge thanks for the code!

Comment: Glad to have been helpful!